# Issues while installing Android Studio "android-studio-ide-141.1980579-linux" on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, android-studio

I have been trying to install this version of Android Studio for last 8 days. Tried installing it with both Oracle Java 1.8 and Open JDK 7 (No Luck!!).

I have also tried downloading different versions of Android Studio (All Stable).

Now here is the thing, I ran the studio.sh file after providing permission using

> sudo chmod +x studio.sh

and

> sudo chmod 777 -R bin

but it is still not able to install the sdk and here is what log says

> Downloading android-sdk_r22.6.2-linux.tgz from https://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r22.6.2-linux.tgz
>   Unpacking android-sdk_r22.6.2-linux.tgz
>   tar xzvfC /tmp/AndroidStudio3FirstRun/android-sdk_r22.6.2-linux.tgz /tmp/AndroidStudio3FirstRun/android-sdk_r22.6.2-linux.tgz-unpacked
>   Refresh Sources:
>     Fetched Add-ons List successfully
>     Refresh Sources
>
> Installing Archives:
>    Preparing to install archives
>
> Installing Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 22
>    Stopping ADB server failed (code -1).
>
> Installed Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 22
>
> Installing Android SDK Build-tools, revision 23 rc3
>
> Installed Android SDK Build-tools, revision 23 rc3
>
> Installing Android SDK Build-tools, revision 22.0.1
>
> Installed Android SDK Build-tools, revision 22.0.1
>
> Download finished with wrong checksum. Expected 5d1bd10fea962b216a0dece1247070164760a9fc, got 26dfa8cb53c2f3edc5c030a6d0d57d54260655ec.
>
> Download finished with wrong checksum. Expected 98320e13976d11597a4a730a8d203ac9a03ed5a6, got 3fe8cef65eb94f20c422ab7d869092786d368eaa.
>
> Download finished with wrong checksum.Expected2c51feb406ce3c7e09db8339a0d680beb91b8bf1, got 0f0a3829ff1ca54a0f3b06d48de7ca8358f2994d.
>
> Download finished with wrong checksum. Expected 09f4445d0e2572e514de60615bc0cc3a7d391558, got f463224a18eb3892f15bd5e483e5e725db6d9502.
>
> Skipping 'Android SDK Tools, revision 24.3.3'; it depends on 'Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 23 rc4' which was not installed.
>
> Skipping 'Google APIs, Android API 22, revision 1'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 5.1.1, API 22, revision 2' which was not installed.
>
> Skipping 'Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image, Google Inc. API 22, revision 1'; it depends on 'Google APIs, Android API 22, revision 1' which was not installed.
>
> Stopping ADB server succeeded.
>
> Starting ADB server succeeded.
>
> Done. 3 packages installed.
>
> source-22, extra-android-m2repository and 5 more SDK components were not installed

It came with a message 
[image: Error!!]

Now after trying everything, Again tried to install via ppa method(that too did not work):

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:paolorotolo/android-studio
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install android-studio

Now please tell me what is the issue going on here, I though trying to download it via wget, flareget or some other download manager, but that too did not work.

Any help would be highly appreciated, I just want to this to setup perfectly than I will start programming again. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I have not got any answer, What should I do??

Comment: Did you try clearing the SDK cache?

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**:

are you trying to install it from within china? If yes then you might have a issue with the connection to google. Post [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26499617/android-sdk-manager-download-finished-with-wrong-checksum) describes the same issue and was fixed by using a vpn. A proxy server would probably work too.

Try ubuntu make. It worked on my machine without any problems.

This [article in the ubuntu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-make) describes how to install ubuntu make and then android studio.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Same issue with it. Download finished with wrong checksum. Expected

Comment: in which directory are you trying to install android studio? did you try to run studio.sh with sudo?

Comment: Home directory!!